Invalid `prisma.user.update()`
This is the error I have.
I'm trying to update the name in db using prisma. I created the action function to perform the update and it says that nome must not be null. But actually is not null, isn't it?
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: "kp_fa1706a59b5348b384c9e62cb0bf59df"
  },
  data: {
+   nome: String
  }
}

Argument `nome` must not be null.

this is the action:
"use server";

import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { prisma } from "./lib/db";
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

export async function updateName() {
  const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
  const user = await getUser();
  const formData = new FormData();

  if (!user) {
    return redirect("/api/auth/login");
  }

  const nome = formData.get("nome");

  try {
    await prisma.user.update({
      where: {
        id: user.id,
      },
      data: {
        nome: nome,
      },
    });

    return {
      message: "Succesfully Updated name",
      status: "green",
    };
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
      if (e.code === "P2002") {
        return {
          message: "This username is alredy used",
          status: "error",
        };
      }
    }

    throw e;
  }
}

this is my prisma schema
model User {
  id                        String @id
  nome                      String
  cognome                   String
  email                     String
  imageUrl                  String?
  Paziente Paziente[]
}

How can I solve the null value for nome (name in english)? Thanks for helping me

Edit:
// this is my action 
"use server";

import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { prisma } from "./lib/db";
// import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

export async function updateName() {
  const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
  const user = await getUser();
  const formData = new FormData();

  if (!user) {
    return redirect("/api/auth/login");
  }

  const nome = formData.get("nome");

  try {
    await prisma.user.update({
      where: {
        id: user.id,
      },
      data: {
        nome: nome,
      },
    });

    return {
      message: "Succesfully Updated name",
      status: "green",
    };
  } catch (e) {
    // if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
    //   if (e.code === "P2002") {
    //     return {
    //       message: "This username is alredy used",
    //       status: "error",
    //     };
    //   }
    // }

    throw e;
  }
}

// this is my form
"use client";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import Link from "next/link";
import { updateName } from "@/app/actions";
import { SubmitButton } from "../utility/SubmitButtons";
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";

const initialState = {
  message: "",
  status: "",
};

export function SettingsForm({ nome }) {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(updateName, initialState);
  const { toast } = useToast();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state?.status === "green") {
      toast({
        title: "Succesfull",
        description: state.message,
      });
    } else if (state?.status === "error") {
      toast({
        title: "Error",
        description: state.message,
        variant: "destructive",
      });
    }
  }, [state, toast]);
  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-extrabold tracking-tight">Settings</h1>

      <Separator className="my-4" />
      <Label className="text-lg">Name</Label>
      <p className="text-muted-foreground">
        In this Settings page you can change your name!
      </p>

      <Input
        defaultValue={nome}
        name="nome"
        required
        className="mt-2"
        min={2}
        maxLength={21}
      />

      {state?.status === "error" && (
        <p className="text-destructive mt-1">{state.message}</p>
      )}

      <div className="w-full flex mt-5 gap-x-5 justify-end">
        <Button variant="secondary" asChild type="button">
          <Link href="/">Cancel</Link>
        </Button>
        <SubmitButton text="Change Username" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

// this is my submit button
"use client";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { ArrowDown, ArrowUp, Loader2 } from "lucide-react";
import { useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

export function SubmitButton({ text }) {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();
  return (
    <>
      {pending ? (
        <Button disabled>
          <Loader2 className="mr-2 w-4 h-4 animate-spin" />
          Please wait
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button type="submit">{text}</Button>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export function SaveButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();
  return (
    <>
      {pending ? (
        <Button className="mt-2 w-full" disabled size="sm">
          <Loader2 className="mr-2 h-3 w-3 animate-spin" />
          Please wait
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button size="sm" className="mt-2 w-full" type="submit">
          Save
        </Button>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export function UpVote() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <>
      {pending ? (
        <Button variant="outline" size="icon" disabled>
          <Loader2 className="h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button variant="outline" size="sm" type="submit">
          <ArrowUp className="h-4 w-4" />
        </Button>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
export function DownVote() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <>
      {pending ? (
        <Button variant="outline" size="icon" disabled>
          <Loader2 className="h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button variant="outline" size="sm" type="submit">
          <ArrowDown className="h-4 w-4" />
        </Button>
      )}
    </>
  );
}


This is the error
This is the log

I think you might need to formData.append("nome", user.name); first.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#examples
I also think maybe formData doesn't do anything here, just update with user.name straightforward.
await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    id: user.id,
  },
  data: {
    nome: user.name,
  },
});

Edit: Here is the code that I used. You can see that second parameter args, which contains the package when you call from client.
You should check this out https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a .
// Client
export const UPDATE_PROFILE = gql`
  mutation UpdateUser($updateUserData: UpdateUserInput!) {
    updateUser(data: $updateUserData) {
      profileImageURL
      backgroundImageURL
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

// Mutation in Server
updateUser: async (parent, args, info) => {
  const { userId, ...updateInfo } = args.data;
  let updatedUser;
  try {
    updatedUser = await prisma.user.update({
      where: {
        id: userId,
      },
      data: {
        ...updateInfo,
      },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }

  return updatedUser;
},

In your code, I don't think that you have passed the username to your function at the backend yet. You should provide it when you call it at frontend. You can update where you call it.
I think the FormData have nothing to do here.

but formData get the name in the form. How can I solve this issue?

Sorry I misunderstood your function a little bit. Can you please help me to console.log(user) and console.log(formData) before you check if that user exist? Please add an update section on the question.

Can you use some screenshot instead please. the log is kinda messed up, remember to snip the user and formData object.

PS: I took the code here https://github.com/ski043/reddit-yt/blob/main/app/components/SettingsForm.tsx

I think you should keep the parameters updateUsername(prevState: any, formData: FormData), removing the parameter and replace it with new FormData() cause the error.
Why you remove it by the way?
https://github.com/ski043/reddit-yt/blob/main/app/actions.ts
Here you can read more about useFormState https://pl.react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormState#using-information-returned-by-a-form-action

ya exactly. done and it works. thanks!!!!
